# Why can't I set a value using the Kademlia example code?

Tags: python, dht, kademlia

I'd like to use a DHT for a project of mine and I'm having trouble getting the [Kademlia example](https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia) working.

Here is the output log from `twistd -noy examples/server.tac`:

```
2015-01-21 18:19:43+0100 [-] Log opened.
2015-01-21 18:19:43+0100 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.6) starting up.
2015-01-21 18:19:43+0100 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2015-01-21 18:19:43+0100 [-] KademliaProtocol starting on 8468
2015-01-21 18:19:49+0100 [-] 'Did not received reply for msg id YES6sdvjJ3qpg5Pr6pg/ajdeMg8= within 5 seconds'
2015-01-21 18:19:49+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] creating spider with peers: []
2015-01-21 18:19:49+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] crawling with nearest: ()
2015-01-21 18:19:49+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] last iteration same as current - checking all in list now
2015-01-21 18:19:53+0100 [Server] [WARNING] No known neighbors, so not writing to cache.
```

And here is the output of the client script found in the link above:

```
2015-01-21 18:22:09+0100 [-] Log opened.
2015-01-21 18:22:09+0100 [-] KademliaProtocol starting on 5678
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [-] 'Did not received reply for msg id SpQjdpv2Qos+C7q0BB1XzNgya4A= within 5 seconds'
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] creating spider with peers: []
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] crawling with nearest: ()
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [NodeSpiderCrawl] [INFO] last iteration same as current - checking all in list now
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [-] Found nodes: []
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [Server] [DEBUG] setting 'a key' = 'a value' on network
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [Server] [WARNING] There are no known neighbors to set key a key
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [Server] [WARNING] There are no known neighbors to get key a key
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [-] Key result: None
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [KademliaProtocol (UDP)] (UDP Port 5678 Closed)
2015-01-21 18:22:14+0100 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

What's going on?  I understand that a peer needs a network to connect to, but isn't that what the standalone server is supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: client/server distinctions don't really exist in a p2p network. so, did you tell node 2 how to contact node 1? And your log files show no temporal overlap, if they're not up at the same time they can't really talk to each other.

Comment: @the8472, The Kademlia docs refer to one of the two scripts as a "standalone server", which I also thought a bit strange.  The two nodes were, in fact, up and running at the same time.  I'm not quite sure what needs to be done in order to "tell node 2 how to contact node 1".  Shouldn't pointing the peer to an ip:port be sufficient?

Comment: "Shouldn't pointing the peer to an ip:port be sufficient?". It should, indeed, but log messages seem to indicate that the nodes have nobody to talk to.

Comment: @the8472, yes, hence my question on StackOverflow ;)  Although admittedly I might have better phrased the question as "why can't these nodes communicate?"

Comment: well, did you adjust the examples to reflect the actual IP addresses of your nodes?

Comment: @the8472, Yes, all nodes are running on my local machine and therefore set to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap address of the client code is incorrect in README file. Example file in the repository [exmaple.py](https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia/blob/master/examples/example.py) has the correct line.

Please change line:

```
server.bootstrap([('127.0.0.1', 1234)]).addCallback(done, server)
```

to

```
server.bootstrap([('127.0.0.1', 8468)]).addCallback(done, server)
```